# PhoneGap Build - Does it set an environment variable to know in code it is being build in phoneGapBuild

Tags: environment-variables, phonegap-build

I want some part of my code to work only when in mobile app, not on web/internet. How can I make it happen without having to change/comment code while loading into phoneGap build?

More specifically, from inside my code, is there a way to find that build is happening inside phoneGap build? Like, is there an environment variable set by phoneGap build that I could check in my code to include mobile app specific code?

Comment: you can check its platform like if(device.platform == "Android" || device.platform == "iOS") then only your code will work.

Comment: No, I need a build time check, not a run time check.